# Nothing happens when clicking on image GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have this code to launch the desired activity when an image from a gridview is clicked:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.drawable.stock:
                    Intent i = new Intent(acceuil.this,carburant.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately, when i tap on the image nothing happens. What is the problem of this code ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The treatement must be done with manipulating the position of the element and not the name of the image, here is the correct code:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                switch (**position**) {
                case **0**:
                    Intent i = new Intent(acceuil.this,carburant.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since the view ID and the drawable ID are not the same this won't work.

If you've implemented GridView like they show in the example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) then you should be able to use the position parameter in `onItemClick()` to retrieve the drawable id from the array and base the switch block on that.  Of course you need to make that value final in order to use switch, but that's not directly relevant.